# log-likelihood in statsmodels vs pymc

Tags: python, python-2.7, statsmodels, pymc, pymc3

I am trying to work through my first maximum likelihood estimation in Python. One of the steps of this requires me to compute the likelihood of your model parameters. I found some sample data that can be summarized here:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
life_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['points', 'time'])
life_test['points'] = np.linspace(1,14,14)
life_test['time'] = np.concatenate((np.linspace(5,40,8), np.linspace(50,100,6)), axis=0)
```

If I run a simple model through statsmodels.api. I get a value of -14.601 from the results.summary().

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
endog=np.array(life_test['points'])
exog=np.array(life_test['time'])
exog = sm.add_constant(exog)
results = sm.OLS(endog, exog).fit()
results.summary()
```

Looking in the source for OLS it seems this is the basic calculation for log-likelihood

```
params = np.array(results.params)
nobs2=results.nobs/2.0 # decimal point is critical here!
-nobs2*np.log(2*np.pi)-nobs2*np.log(1.0/(2*nobs2) *\
    np.dot(np.transpose(endog - np.dot(exog, params)),\
    (endog - np.dot(exog,params)))) - nobs2
```

When I try to implement this with PyMC I get different results. It may be some miscalculation of the loc and scale on my part.

```
import pymc.distributions as dist
mu = exog.mean()
sigma = exog.std()
dist.normal_like(exog, mu, 1/sigma**2)
```

Here I get a value of -135.29. I feel I must be miscalculating my scale and loc values, but it may be some other error in my implementation. Perhaps OLS is using some other likelihood besides the normal log-likelihood? I am pretty new to statsmodels, PyMC, and MLE in general. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your pymc likelihood is the likelihood from the regression of exog on a constant, which is just mean and var. Your OLS regression is completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can compare the result from `statsmodels` with `sklearn` using:

```
>>> x=sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False).fit(exog,endog)
>>> x.coef_
array([ 1.45714286,  0.13428571])
```

which is comparable with

```
>>> sm.OLS(endog, exog).fit().params
array([ 1.45714286,  0.13428571])
```

the results are consistant. On the otherhand, it seems you just computed the likelihood of fitting a `gaussian` to `exog` data which is different from `linear-reqression`.

In order to recreate `linear regression` with `pymc` you need to do as following:

- defining your model free parameters with a set of priors
- give your input data to pass through your model with different values of free parameters
- At the end, set up your `Gaussian` likelihood

So the implementaton with pymc is:

```
life_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['points', 'time'])
life_test['points'] = np.linspace(1,14,14)
life_test['time'] = np.concatenate((np.linspace(5,40,8), np.linspace(50,100,6)), axis=0)
endog=np.array(life_test['points'])
exog=np.array(life_test['time'])
alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, tau=2)
beta = pm.Normal('beta', mu=0, tau=2)
sigma = pm.Uniform('sigma', lower=0, upper=1)
y_est = alpha + beta * exog
radon_like = pm.Normal('y', mu=y_est, tau=sigma, observed=True,value=endog)
model = dict(rand_like=radon_like,alpha=alpha,beta=beta,sigma=sigma)
S = pm.MCMC(model)
S.sample(iter=100000,burn=1000)
pm.Matplot.plot(S)
```

If you compute the loglikelihood with the following procedure, you will get the close results by using `pm.normal_like` distribution:

```
>>> results = sm.OLS(endog, exog).fit()
>>> y_est = results.params[0] + results.params[1] * exog[:,1]
>>> pm.normal_like(endog, y_est, 1/np.sqrt(y_est.std()))
-19.348540432740464
```

Comment: Thanks! A lot of good information here I'll try to sort through. I guess the problem I've been having is knowing how to properly determine the log-likelihood. I thought that keeping it a normal distribution would make it simpler. I have some data where the endogenous variable is normally distributed. I can get my starting parameters using OLS.

Comment: ^ log-likelihood of the model to be precise.

Comment: @user14241 sometimes it is better you write your own likelihood instead of using a `black box` of a library unless you have understood the theory behind very well.

Comment: @user14241 so I reckon I didn't understand your question very well, or your original problem wasn't very clear.

Comment: @user14241 I updated my answer using `pm.normal_like` to estimate **loglikelihood** using `pymc` distributions. I think it is what you are looking for?!!!

Comment: I think you answered my question fine. The basic question was what's the difference between the two, and you answered that. I guess I never really told you why I was looking for this. Basically, I've been trying for several days to get a MLE to work in statsmodels (using GenericLikelihoodModel class). So far I haven't had any luck getting it to work. But I'm getting closer. The example code provided is using a binomial distribution, but my data is continuous (and different from the example data I provided). Ultimately, I want to use the output for model inference. I appreciate all your help.